# Selecting more than one table with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables - users, roles, and role_user. Each user is assigned to a role in the role_user table and the list of roles is found on the roles table. I want to select all users with role id of 12. I am currently doing this with the query builder but I need it to be in eloquent format. I am not really good with Laravel eloquent, please I need help in convert the queries to eloquent.
This is what I am currently doing:

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
            ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
            ->where('roles.id', '=', 12)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your same DB query in an eloquent format, you would have to do the following:

1. You should have a User model created which should be created with your project if you enabled laravel authentication which you could read more on [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication).  If not you have to create your Models.
2. To use the Models in your controller or Class, you have to enable it in your php file:

   `use App\User;`
3. Run your reference to the User model like so.

   `$users = User::join('role_user','users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
       ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
       -> where('roles.id', '=', 12)
       ->get();`

$users will now be a collection and subject to all the great methods available with a collection.

I suggest taking some time to run through a free video tutorial on laracast to really understand how Model's are used with Eloquent.  Additionally would be good to review the out of the box Auth features available.  I tend to make all my calls to roles using Auth.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

With Eloquent its very easy to retrieve relational data checkout following example with your scenario in Laravel 5

we have three models

1) Users ( has one role_user )

2) Roles (has many role_user)

3) RoleUser (belongs to User and Role )

1) Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
 use Eloquent;

class Users extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function userrole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\RoleUser');
    }

}
```

2) Roles.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Roles extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "roles";

    public function rolesuser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RoleUser');
    }

}
```

2) RoleUser.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
 use Eloquent;

class RoleUser extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'role_user';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users');
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Roles');
    }

}
```

You need to check you database has relation and setup in models. Users has one role in role_user table. Role has many roles for users in role_user table. Role User belong to users and role. Once you setup the relationships in laravel/database, it becomes easy to retrieve the related information.

For example, if you want to retrieve an users by using the userrole, you would need to write:

```
$users = \App\Models\Users::with(['userrole'])->first();
```

If you want to get user role name than you can write:

```
$users->userrole->role->rolename; 
/* here rolename the column name you have in role table for role name*/
```

**Now come to your query: You want to select those users only who has role id 12. It's now becomes simple to write in eloquent format.**

```
$users = \App\Models\RoleUser::where('role_id', 12)->with(['user', 'role'])->get(); 
/* Here role_id is the column you have in role_user table as reference for role table */
```

you can learn more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

This will give the uses with role id of 12:

```
User::whereHas( 'roles', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where( 'id', 12 );
        } )->get();
```

I assumed u set up the relationships correctly.

If u want dynamically pass the $role_id, then use the following:

```
User::whereHas( 'roles', function ( $query ) use ($role_id) {
            $query->where( 'id', $role_id );
        } )->get();
```

Comment: Did you get the question well? Users table are tired to role_user table and roles table simply has the list of roles. Roles table is not related to the users table. Please see the query in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In role Model you should add this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User','role_id','id');
}
```

In Controller

```
$allusrs = Role::with('users')->where('id','=','12');
dd($allusrs);
```

Comment: Did you get the question well? Users table are tired to role_user table and roles table simply has the list of roles. Roles table is not related to the users table. Please see the query in my question.